# How do I enter a verification code after it's sent to a trusted device

Tags: apple-id, two-factor-authentication

After updating OSX, the device wants to verify my applied through two factor authentication. Its sent a text message with a verification code to a trusted device, but won't progress to a dialog where I can enter the verification code, but keeps spinning next to my phone number.
 How do I sign in?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having a similar problem. My father in law died and left us a MacBook Air (11” early 2015) I have added myself as an Administrator and am trying to give it access to my ICloud material. This MacBook is running OS Sierra Ver. 10.12.4. Two factor authorization has been activated and a dialogue box opens to accept a verification code from one of my other devices. My IPhone has supplied a verification code but the MacBook dialogue box will not provide the boxes for the code’s entry. All I can get is a spinning circle of dots.

Comment: No @RPerry I haven't found a solution.